# Spring rest Json web service with exception Handler

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am getting an unconditional issue. I made my REST services in spring Json based. My service suppose to work with "Content-Type application/json" but whenever I made request  without content-type then it throws an exception.

```
 org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

However I am handling this exception with @ExceptionHandler , but spring is not able to handle this exception and my control is not coming in @ExceptionHandler method.

Please advice!  how I can make sure that my incoming request needs to send content-type header ??

I wanted to catch this exception in my @ExceptionHandler method so that I can send error message with error code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<ReponseWrapper> login(@Valid LoginRequest loginRequest,
        BindingResult results,) {
    //any code
}



 @ExceptionHandler(HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> handleUnsupportedMediaTypeException(HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException ex) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Object>  map = Maps.newHashMap();
        map.put("error", "Unsupported Media Type");
        map.put("cause", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        map.put("supported", ex.getSupportedMediaTypes());
        return map;
    }
```

Comment: try `produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"` instead of `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`

Comment: Have you configured any exception resolvors in the application context?

Comment: you may use a  filter to verify the request  before it reaches the controller and also check the content type avoid such request may be it is one of  the way.may  be you can try this approach

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first issue is that @ExceptionHandler annotations on your controller methods handle only the exceptions thrown from within your controller; the exception that you experience gets thrown before the controller method is invoked and therefore does not get handled.

It would get handled if you had a case like this:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = 
        APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseWrapper> test(LoginRequest request)
        throws HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException {
        throw new HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException("");
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> handleUnsupportedMediaTypeException(
        HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException ex) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Object> map = Maps.newHashMap();
        map.put("error", "Unsupported Media Type");
        map.put("cause", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        map.put("supported", ex.getSupportedMediaTypes());
        return map;
    }
}
```

I suspect you would have to extend ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver that would process only HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException types. Or refer to [this page](https://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/spring-mvc-part-v-exception-handling/) and see if it helps.

Also, see whether you can use a newer version of Spring.

Answer (score -2):

The `@ExceptionHanlder` annotation is not working because you have an invalid return type. The return type can be a String, which is interpreted as a view name or a ModelAndView object.

Comment: That is not correct. Since OP is using `@ResponseBody` then returned map is converted toJSON string automatically. Read more about it..